# Django 1.5 on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm having some difficulties setting up Django 1.5 to run via the dev_appserver.py, rather than the manage.py runserver.

The project directory is as such:

- env
- myproject

  - manage.py
  - myproject

    - init, settings, urls, wsgi (.py)

I've tried to two following ways to get it working with the App Engines appserver:

app.yaml:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.5"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

as suggested from this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django

It does not produce any error when setting the up the local server, but when I access the given link, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: django must be included in the "libraries:" clause of your app.yaml file when using the django_wsgi builtin.
```

---

Next I've tried it in a slightly different way.
With app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.5"
```

and a main.py as such:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

which produces the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Mello\AppEngine\02\myproject\main.py", line 4, in module>
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Even though if I run

```
>>>import django.core.handlers.wsgi
>>>
```

in the same virtual environment, it runs fine.

---

Anybody has any piece of advice to point me in the right direction to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I am working on brand new docs for Django on App Engine that will be released very soon. The short version of the story is that we don't recommend the built-in Django version since it's super out of date. Instead, use pip -t to vendor a more recent Django version. Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/appengine-django-skeleton

Comment: Cool, thats great news. I though it was strange that I couldnt access the 'Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine' article anymore, and I guess this explains it. Thanks a lot for the heads up. I will take a look at that skeleton. Thank you, again.

Comment: Although @BillPrin suggested not to use the built-in Django, I would like to suggest a possible cause of the problem for whom may concern. If you install a separate version of Django in your project environment, it collides with the built-in Django and results in RuntimeError of the first case. Simply remove Django from your environment in order to use the Django provided by App Engine.

Comment: @asitaru If you're  vendoring Djagno you should not use the built-in version as well. However, the Django built-in versions have been upgraded so I may start recommending them again very soon.

Comment: @BillPrin You are absolutely right. But this is an easy mistake to make when you use pip to install a library requiring Django. Since pip doesn't recognize app.yaml settings, it will install another Django in your environment.